# Mid 1980s SF book with human colonists on a forest world

Tags: story-identification, books

1. Not the *Mid World* books or the LeGuin forest book
2. Human colonists on a forest planet, want to be independent from Earth
3. Author’s first name might have been Christopher
4. Planet was definitely outside this solar system- in fact, the story referenced that the human colonists had left the solar system after previously colonizing the outer planets.
5. I don’t remember any character names. Only character attribute I remember is the main antagonist, a very technocratic Earth admiral trying to assert control by force.
6. No sex that I recall - I would have been 12-13 when I read.
7. Tone was much more sci fi than fantasy; detailed descriptions of the Earth ships and the colonists’ defenses. There were several battles.

Comment: It is a little amusing to read: "Planet was definitely outside this solar system- in fact, the human colonists had deliberately left the solar system. ".  The distances to even the nearest stars are about 10,000 times the distances to other planets in our solar system, so accidentally leaving the solar system to colonize an exoplanet would be highly unusual.

Comment: One other possibility is _[Downbelow Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downbelow_Station)_ by CJ Cherryh - it's in the right time frame, there is a technocratic admiral trying to take over and a forest planet -- but the humans mostly live on a space station and mostly leave the planet to the natives.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Doesn’t appear to be Downbelow Station but will check that out in its own right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After continued searching of cover art, the book I was thinking of is Christopher Rowley’s [“The War for Eternity”](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1958540.The_War_for_Eternity) (1983).

> The bearlike aliens of Fenrille had long been allies of the fiercely independent human clans. Together Men and Felin ruled the wooded highlands of the odd planet's single continent. And together they grew rich, for only the poeple of the highlands could harvest the drug that kept men forever young. Then the masters of a distant Earth sent a starfleet with a force of brutal Space Marines to seize the planet. But they weren't prepated for the colonists' stiff resistance- and no one had warned them of the aliens' very special defenses.

Comment: I don't think I would ever have got that book from your description..most people remember the chitin bugs when they talk about TWFE!

Comment: Gave the check mark, thanks for the prompt.  For some reason, I don’t remember the chitin bugs.  Anyway, paperback is on the way, thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Is it [*The Word for World Is Forest*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Word_for_World_Is_Forest) (1972), a science fiction novella by American writer Ursula K. Le Guin?

> The Word for World Is Forest is the Humans As Invader flavor of alien invasion stories. Earthlings land on an Eden-like forest planet and immediately begin chopping down what they can and enslaving everything else. 
>   [Source](https://best-sci-fi-books.com/29-best-alien-invasion-science-fiction-books/)

The narrative can be a little heavy-handed, but it’s more about the forced loss of innocence than simply beating the drum for conservation.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  No, it was definitely published in the 1983-1986 timeframe, with a male author, and the human colonists were trying to live in harmony with the planet, but the Earth based power structure was trying to control them.

Comment: Was the planet in the solar system? Who was the main character? His abilities? What was the tone of the book? Was there description of sex? How much death and violence was in the book? What about scientific jargon?

Comment: Thank you for prompting me / jogging my memory.  Planet was definitely outside this solar system- in fact, the human colonists had deliberately left the solar system.  I don’t remember any character names.  Only character attribute I remember is the main anatagonist, a very technocratic Earth admiral trying to assert control by force.  No sex that I recall - I would have been 12-13 when I read.  Tone was much more sci fi than fantasy; detailed descriptions of the Earth ships and the colonists’ defenses.  There were several battles.